# Javascript ignores multi-dimensional associative array keys/values - whats wrong here?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

What is the problem here?

**First example:**

```
console.log(ntags);
console.log(JSON.stringify(ntags));
```

Console output (Google Chrome):

```
[Array[0], Array[0]]
    0: Array[0]
        length: 0
        numerical_value: null
        tag_id: "3"
    1: Array[0]
        length: 0
        numerical_value: "12"
        tag_id: "5"


[[],[]]
```

Obviously the variable "ntags" is populated with a certain number of associative arrays which have certain values. However JSON.stringify makes an empty array.

**Second example** - the same problem occures if I try to post the variable ntags with Ajax directly:

```
$.ajax({ type:"POST", url: "/?tag_connection=update&fdata_id="+save_id, data: {cons: ntags}, success: function(result){
...
});
```

The client does not send any post data to the server side ($_POST empty in PHP).

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have associative arrays.

Comment: Given that both the child arrays are empty, the JSON output looks correct.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan yes it's unclear, however a likely reason for confusion might be that it's perfectly OK to use non-numeric property names for Array instance properties, but they won't be serialized via `JSON.stringify()`.

Comment: You should use `Objects` not `Arrays` for associative values. Like @Pointy said, the output is whats expected (You don't expect `[0,1,2]` to output as `[0,1,2,length:3]`, right?)

Comment: @somethinghere That should solve the problem however what is the reason object properties are serailized and array properties are not?

Comment: It simply comes down to how Serialisation works - when it gets an array, even though it is technically also an object, it will only serialise the values - because that's intrinsic to an `Array`, nobody would expect properties to be serialised when an array is being serialised.

Comment: @somethinghere Ok I see you can make an answer from that if you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON serialising does not serialise properties of an `Array`, this is simply not the expected behaviour - an array is a list of values, in order. The properties for this do not get serialised simply because *it is not expected behaviour*. You could technically serialise this, but it would defeat the point of having an Array as a data type.

For example, let's say we serialise the array `[1,2,3,4]` - then the expected output in JSON is:

```
[1,2,3,4]
```

simply because of it's *type*. If arrays were serialised like objects, the output might look something like this:

```
{0:1,1:2,2:3,4:4,length:4}
```

As you can see this is much longer - which means more data you need to send over a network, and a custom object to be created in any other programming language. This way we all agree on arrays.

So in this instance, you might just want to use an object, which will output the expected value. Try serialising this:

```
[{length:0,numerical_value: null, tag_id: 3}, {length: 0, numerical_value: null, tag_id:2}]
```